# how to add example for RuleBasedStateMachine in python hypothesis

Tags: python-hypothesis

we can use @example for a normal test as following:

```
@given(text())
@example("Hello world")
@example(x="Some very long string")
def test_some_code(x):
    pass
```

but how to reproduce failures for RuleBasedStateMachine with @example?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent to `@example()` for `RuleBasedStateMachine` - instead, we recommend writing specific cases as traditional unit tests.

Comment: I'd actually love to support one, but nobody has managed to design an interface which handles all the complicated interactions of stateful testing.  The `st.data()`, `st.randoms()`, and `st.functions()` strategies are also incompatible with `@example(...)` :-(